# Remove hour from time input

Tags: html, input-field

Is there a way to display an input with type `time`, so that only display `mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss`? Note it only needs to work in latest chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is quite a really new feature, and you can't do that for now ; HTML5 specifications states that the time input should accept a valid *partial-time* as defined in RFC 3339 [1](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.time.html)

This specification defines *partial-time* as [2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-6) :

> time-hour ":" time-minute ":" time-second

In fact, these definitions are used to represent the **wire format**, then the browser is able to show this input like he wants ; basically, Chrome displays time input according to the user locale, so you can't really have an hand on it [3](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161024).

**References**

1. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.time.html
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-6
3. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161024